# Android build miss intellij

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build

since today I cannot build my android project because of this error :

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find intellij-core.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.0.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.0.1/intellij-core-26.0.1.jar
```

Android studio 3.2.1
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1

Do you have any clue ???
Thanks a lot

Vlad

Comment: same here, and over there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946371/android-studio-could-not-find-intellij-core-jar

Comment: where should I put those files (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.external.com-intellij/intellij-core/26.0.1) in order to be able to build again ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with a cordova-android@7.1.1 project. I read this question [Android Studio - Could not find intellij-core.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52946371/1155718) and I solved by joining more than one answer.

*Premise:*

- Android Studio 3.2.1
- Cordova Android 7.1.1
- Cordova Cli 8.1.2

*Resolution:*

File: **platforms/android/build.gradle**

```
...
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
...
```

File: **platforms/android/app/build.gradle**

```
...
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
...
```

File: **platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle**

```
...
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
    }
}
...
```

This solution is working to me, I hope I helped you

Comment: Anyone familiar with a plugin / hook to do this, as my problem is on my CI server?

Comment: I think writing a hook for this problem is very expensive. There is already a pull request to solve this problem https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/525. We hope they will release an update as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues, and change to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'` solve my issues. You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is heavily based on the ionic article: https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005529314*

This script can be added to the hooks so no need to fiddle with the platforms code manually.

Create a `maven_swap.sh` with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

#remove jcenter
sed -i.bak '/jcenter()/d' platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle
#append jcenter
sed -i.bak  '/maven {/{
N
N
a\
jcenter()
}' platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle
cat platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle
rm platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle.bak
```

note: `sed -i.bak` ensures linux & mac compatibility.

Make sure the file is executable `chmod +x maven_swap.sh`

Add in the `config.xml` the following:

```
<platform name="android">
    <hook src="maven_swap.sh" type="before_compile" />
    ...
</platform>
```