# Android Studio - Could not find intellij-core.jar

Tags: maven, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using android studio 3.1.4.

Error:Could not find intellij-core.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.0.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.0.1/intellij-core-26.0.1.jar

Comment: For anyone arriving here due to the _same_ error message when building for Android in Unity, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52957079/gradle-build-for-android-in-unity-fails-saying-that-it-could-not-find-intellij) SO question for a slightly different solution.

Comment: possible duplicate with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51072319/android-studio-3-1-3-gradle-sync-error-could-not-download-gradle-core-jar/51151050#51151050

Comment: None of the answers have solved my issue. Getting the same error on a React Native project.

Comment: I am also getting the same

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying to follow the instructions for setting up and running Flutter on Linux: https://flutter.io/setup-linux/ None of the provided answers have worked so far.

Comment: @burakcalik if that's a problem with on of the sub-modules you're using, it may be that this submodule has a wrong order amongst it's dependencies and not your :app module itself. I experienced that here https://github.com/square/react-native-square-reader-sdk/issues/30

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by changing the order of the repositories here:

`/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle`

from this:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

to this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: where is /platforms/android/CordovaLib (on Windows)?

Comment: Manually editing files in `platforms` is recipe for disaster.

Comment: it so tricky, I try to edit platforms/build.gradle and it not working ulti I findout that CordovaLib have the same file name

Comment: How would you proceed, If gradle simply ignores the `google()` line and proceeds to use `jcenter()`?

Answer (score 15):

If you're using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'` or higher in your project/build.gradle, the solution is:

Add `"google()"` to your **project/build.gradle** file in 2 places:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

Then you will see in the logs that **intellij-core.jar** is downloaded from different URLs:

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.0.1/intellij-core-26.0.1.pom
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.0.1/intellij-core-26.0.1.jar

Comment: Check my answer. It's better to upgrade to android-cordova 7.1.1 than to manually edit your build.gradle files.

Comment: Manually editing files in `platforms` is recipe for disaster.

Comment: It might be weird, but when I added the "maven..." to the top, it finally worked for me

Answer (score 7):

To resolve this issue either put

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="27" />
```

into your **config.xml**.

Or even better, upgrade android-cordova to the lates version (7.1.2):

```
cordova platform add android@7.1.2
```

android-cordova 7.1.2 includes fix CB-14127: "Move google maven repo ahead of jcenter". (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-14127)

Comment: upgrading to android-cordova 7.1.1 doesn't fix the problem, as stated in other comments the problem is still reproducible

Comment: They fixed it in /platforms/adnroid/build.gradle but not in /platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle so the build still fails

Answer (score 7):

I solve my problem; change the platform/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle file. I put the maven repo ahead the jcenter:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    jcenter()

}
```

And I use cordova-android 7.1.1.

Answer (score 3):

hey guys I came across the same problem, which is actually a conflict between the ionic, gradle and gradle plugin. It turns out that in the new version of the gradle plugin the build is now dependent on the google repository. To get around the problem you need to change 2 files:

Make sure they are as described below!

1 ° - “platforms / android / CordovaLib / build.gradle”

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
  google()
  maven {
   url “https://maven.google.com”
  }
  jcenter ()
}
```

2 ° - “platforms / android / build.gradle”

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
  google()
  maven {
   url “https://maven.google.com”
  }
  jcenter ()
 }
```

and

```
 allprojects {
  repositories {
  google()
  maven {
   url “https://maven.google.com”
  }
  jcenter ()
 }
```

This is it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

**For me, problem solved change build gradle files to get Google Server.**
/platforms/android/build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
```

/platforms/android/app/build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
    }
```

Comment: Manually editing files in `platforms` is recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/23397

In short, following Mahi-K from the above link, you have to edit `$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}
```

In the gradle wrapper properties `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` you may also have to change it to 4.6 or above

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Use
    com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1

You'll also have to update your '/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties'

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Comment: Of course you'll run into further issue with older apis like aapt etc.
Another workaround is to just copy someone else's existing '~/.gradle' folder to your '~/'.
But that's just a barbaric hack. :-D

Comment: didn't fix it for me

Answer (score 1):

In addition to devsnd and Mr-IDE's answers, Here are the suggestions:

- Place 'google()' in the first order in both buildscript repositories and 
  allprojects repositories of Project-level Gradle build file.
- Check the consistency in the Android Gradle Plugin version and Gradle version. 
  Generally, they are automatically updated with Android Studio, but you might have an older project. Plugin 3.1 should use Gradle version 4.4 and above, Plugin 3.2 should use Gradle version 4.6 and above.
- Install that particular buildToolsVersion that plugin uses.

Check out this link for more details:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Adding google() to the build.gradle files uses this URL https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/ which returns 404 at the moment.

(source: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html#google--)

At the moment, the working URL is https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html 
You can reach it by replacing google() with this line

maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

in your build.gradle files.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is being [tracked on Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-14127)

**A break down of the issue**

> Basically there was a problem uploading Google jars to jcenter and it is causing builds to fail.

**The fix**

> Builds will work if we put the google maven repo ahead of jcenter.

On the 18th July the issue should have been addressed in the release of cordova-android 7.1.1, [see change log here](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2018/07/18/cordova-android-7.1.1.html)

The fix however did not work in all cases evidently.

A [new fix has been made](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/523) so expect this to be ready in 7.1.2, until then, remember to swap the ordering every time you remove and re-add the platform.

Comment: Is that under allprojects, buildscript or both?

Comment: @JonathanRys Just in `buildscript`> `repositories`. in file `platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle`

Comment: Got it.  This also works for a similar issue with react-native-camera build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to:

**com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0**

form

**com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1**

Solved the Problem

also: i put **google()** at first

*I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1*

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was going to the Build.Gradle, and going to where it says the following:

dependencies {
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"

If you are getting the same Tag Mismatch issue I got from this error, then click on the highlighted "com.android.tools.build:gradle" part and then press alt enter.

If it asks you to sync, sync, then click it again and press Alt Enter and it should ask you to upgrade. Click yes. It will upgrade to the latest version.

Now generate your signed APK and it should work now.

That is, if the lint is highlighting it. If it isn't than I don't know what the problem is.

It could be the result of an older Gradle dependency changing and a newer one taking precedence. That's my theory. I fixed my problem anyhow.