# Gradle build for Android in Unity fails, saying that it could not find intellij-core.jar

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, build

So thats what I have tried:

- Building different projects (same thing)
- Reinstalling sdk, jdk, and Unity Editor (newbie gotos)

I have also found very similar problem from today: [Android Studio - Could not find intellij-core.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946371/android-studio-could-not-find-intellij-core-jar)
yet the only gradle.build file that I found was the one generated with Unity in Temp folder that overwrites itself after every build start.

Unity 2018.2.13f1, Windows 10 x64, Fresh Android Studio 3.2.1, jdk1.8.0_192

**Here is a console log:** 
Short

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'gradleOut'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find intellij-core.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.0.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.0.1/intellij-core-26.0.1.jar
```

Long

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity Editors\2018.2.13f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.2.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'gradleOut'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find intellij-core.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.0.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.0.1/intellij-core-26.0.1.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's what worked for me, as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946371/android-studio-could-not-find-intellij-core-jar):

1. Go into the **Player Settings**
2. Under **Publishing Settings** tick the box for **Custom Gradle Template** (Unity then creates a build.gradle template for you)
3. The template is in Assets > Plugins > Android > mainTemplate.gradle
4. Open that file in something like Notepad
5. Change *ONLY THIS*:

   `repositories { jcenter() google() }`
   to
   `repositories { google() jcenter() }`
6. Save the file then try the build again. Not a perfect solution but it should work until Unity/Android fixes the issue. I'm not sure whether this can become undone by upgrading Unity, but I do know that it has to be done per project.

Comment: Thanks for posting the link in the other thread regardless of what they said. Appreciate it!

Comment: So helpful! Thanks for the share!

Answer (score 3):

Here's the only solution that worked for me since **I'm behind a proxy**.

1. Go to the `.gradle folder` (default is under `C:\Users\<name>\`).
2. Create a file called `gradle.properties` under this folder.
3. Add the following:

---

```
#http proxy setup
systemProp.http.proxyHost=<your proxy URL>
systemProp.http.proxyPort=<your proxy Port>
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost

#https proxy setup
systemProp.https.proxyHost=<your proxy URL>
systemProp.https.proxyPort=<your proxy Port>
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

4. Reopen unity and build !

Comment: Gradle doesn't follow proxy settings in env variables nor the settings of Unity. That's the point.

Answer (score 2):

If Glen's answer did not work for you, **do his steps again** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52958384/6046022) **with some edits**:

1. change `repositories` in `Assets > Plugins > Android > mainTemplate.gradle` to this:

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

2. **I guess this was my problem:** make sure your internet connection to repositories is ok! in some countries there are restrictions. In that case you need a VPN.
3. Last step restart Unity

Build took a few minutes but it worked

I also updated gradle: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1490992/change-version-of-gradle-to-46.html
but not sure if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the  Assets > Plugins > Android > mainTemplate.gradle is already with jcenter() call, so I just check 'Custom Gradle Template' and works!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working! Got the same error, using Firebase also, so the mentioned fix here wouldn't help because Firebase keeps overwriting my gradle template. Here is the answer:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/commandinvokationfailure-gradle-build-failed.573040/

Best of luck!