# Started getting "Could not find intellij-core.jar" today all of sudden

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Today all of sudden I started getting below error on my Jenkins server while building app using git pr branch

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find intellij-core.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.0.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.0.1/intellij-core-26.0.1.jar
```

As I can see there is no android folder itself on  https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/ .  Is there any change  in repo location .

Also tried using jcenter repo, but still facing same issue.

Any suggestions/workaround for this ?

Comment: [Please do check with this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52952806/9254960) add maven url and google() in build.gradle(project)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this link. It's working now .

Comment: doing that "google()" trick didnt solve it for me.......

Comment: Right.  This putting google() at first  worked for older combination of gradle/sdk tools plugin . But its not working for some latest combination . Unable  to figure out what combination of tools/plugin is cause.
When I tried ran build with gradle debug mode, I can see that no matter what  "Gradle Central Plugin Repository" is used by build tools to resolve components. 

"Attempting to resolve component for com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.1 using repositories [Gradle Central Plugin Repository,  Google,BintrayJCenter] "