# Could not find intellij-core.jar in React Native

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to Sync a React-Native project in Android studio, whenever I try to sync it, it throws an error as below,

```
Could not find intellij-core.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.0.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.0.1/intellij-core-26.0.1.jaa r
```

I tried lot of methods mentioned earlier for the same issue for Cordova and other project But I can't see it work for my React-Native.

My build.gradle file is looks like following

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

Duplicated Questions answers are looks like for Cordova, but My question is about to React-Native, and I tried all the answers there none of they are not working

Comment: You should be targeting the same API version as your compile and your support.

Comment: @TheWanderer, not getting you, can you elaborate please?

Comment: You shouldn't be targeting API 26 while compiling with API 27 and using the API 27 support library versions.

Comment: So targetSdkVersion should be 27?

Comment: Yes. It should be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - Could not find intellij-core.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946371/android-studio-could-not-find-intellij-core-jar)

Comment: I tried but not working, why Duplicate? I am asking for React-Native, the actual Answers in the above Duplicate is for Cordova isn't it?

Comment: It shouldn't matter. It's a Java library, not Cordova or React.

Comment: Ok,but it's not working for me, I tried all the Answers mentioned

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51151050/8034839 please

Answer (score 0):

It appears that jcenter was broken yesterday.  In your `build.gradle` file, move `jcenter()` below `google()` (both places).

For more information:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21907#issuecomment-432319128

Answer (score 0):

Make this particular change under android/**CordovaLib**/build.gradle

```
repositories {maven {
url "https://maven.google.com"} jcenter()}
```

Note: add jcenter() after maven and use cordova **platform add android@7.1.1** to add platfrom